# Service is not included in deployed pages

Tags: angular, typescript, basic-authentication

I'm new to angular, I wrote an interceptor to test Basic Authentication, the problem is that the interceptor is never called. So I tried to launch my application in debug mode and what I discovered that interceptor is not included in deployed pages.
Is it a logic behavior?

Here my Interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BasicAuthenticationHtppInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

      constructor() { }

      intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

      if (sessionStorage.getItem('username') && sessionStorage.getItem('token')) {
          req = req.clone({
          setHeaders: {
              Authorization: JSON.stringify(sessionStorage.getItem('token'))
          }})
      }

      return next.handle(req);

    }
 }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main module, you should have something like:

```
 providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: BasicAuthenticationHtppInterceptorService,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

See https://angular.io/guide/http-intercept-requests-and-responses for more explaination

Answer (score 1):

Your App.module file should look like something like this:

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
     YourComponents

  ],
  imports: [
      YourModules
  ],
  providers: [{
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: BasicAuthenticationHtppInterceptorService,
      multi: true

  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})
export class AppModule { 


}
```